# Why is it not updating

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

I'm trying to update my database where in the Book copies will be updated to 5 depending on the Book code.

The Book copies I initialize in the database was 10. For now, I have a fixed value of 5 to change it. My plan is to decrement the copies by 1 if users borrowed it. But for now, I'm trying to learn how to update the book first if it will work.

Here's my code where the Book copies in my database still hasn't updated to 5.

```
try{
    con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby://localhost:1510/LibSyst", "student", "student");
    String updating = "UPDATE BOOKS SET copies = ? WHERE code = ?";
    ps = con.prepareStatement(updating);

    //trying to convert String to Int here
    String strCOde = bookCode.getText();
    int intCode = Integer.parseInt(strCOde);
    
    ps.setInt(7, 5);
    ps.setInt(1, intCode);
    ps.executeUpdate();
        
}catch (Exception e ){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Update Failed");
}
```

Also, the copies data type is numeric, is that right?

Comment: ```ps.setInt(7, 5);```. What are you doing here? It should be ```ps.setInt(2, 5);```.   The rest looks fine to update your record.

Comment: @Ashish I'm Updating the Book Copies to 5. The number 7 is the Position of the BookCopies in the table and the number 5 is the fixed value that I want number 10 to be converted to. This is the sample code I followed >> https://alvinalexander.com/blog/post/jdbc/sample-jdbc-preparedstatement-sql-update/

Comment: Instead of only printing a generic message like _"Update Failed"_, make sure you also log the entire exception, so you can inspect what/why it failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are making a silly mistake. The index in the prepared statement start from 1, so just make these changes it will work as expected.

```
 ps.setInt(1, 5);
 ps.setInt(2, intCode);
```

Comment: I tried this and it worked thank you!!;-; i thought the first numbers inside the parenthesis was the position of the column in the table huhu

Comment: @roboto you need to do this exactly.

Comment: @Ashish I tried it and it worked! thank you all for helping me!

Comment: @roboto The index is the 1-based index of the parameter in the query text (first `?` is 1, second is 2, etc.)